# Playing sound using pygame (python)

Tags: python, pygame, playback

As of right now I have a program that plays individual sounds based on a certain key presses. Each key press successfully plays the correct sound based on the key pressed, but the sound is cut off when the next sound from a different key begins to play. I want to know how to have my program play the sounds from each key in their entirety, even when another key is pressed and a new sound begins to play (I want the sounds to play simultaneously). I am using the pygame and keyboard libraries.

Here is the function I am using to play sounds for the keys:

```
# 'keys' refers to a dictionary that has the key press strings and sound file names stored as key-value pairs.
key = keyboard.read_key() 
def sound(key):
    play = keys.get(key, 'sounds/c2.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(play)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

If you need more context, please tell me and I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pygame, you can play multiple sound tracks simultaneously using channels. Note that channels only support wav or ogg files.

Here is some sample code. Press keys 1-3 to start a track. You can also start the same track multiple times.

```
import pygame

lst = [
'Before The Brave - Free.wav',   # key 1
'Imagine Dragons - Demons.wav',  # key 2
'Shinedown-How Did You Love.wav' # key 3
]

pygame.init()
size = (250, 250)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.mixer.init()
print("channel cnt",pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()) # max track count (8 on my machine)

while True: 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    idx = 0
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_1]: idx = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_2]: idx = 2
    if keys[pygame.K_3]: idx = 3
    if (idx):
       ch = pygame.mixer.find_channel() # find open channel, returns None if all channels used
       snd = pygame.mixer.Sound(lst[idx-1])  # create sound object, must be wav or ogg
       if (ch): ch.play(snd)  # play on channel if available
```

Comment: I used some of your code and it works well. The only issue is that I need more than eight channels. How would I increase the number of available channels? If I can't, is there any way to keep the program running after it returns "none", or will I have to find a way to clear the channels so that there is always 1 available channel?

Comment: Answer updated to check for None. If the channels are full and you want another sound, you will need to stop one of the channels and replace the sound file.